# Does anyone know what angle it should be?

Tags: javascript, angle

I've got myself a game, the shooting of the player is working fine but that's because I'm using an on.click event and some maths but now I'm trying to get the enemy to shoot back to my player.

me is just the enemy, so `me.x` and `me.y` is the x and the y of the enemy.

p is the player so `p.x` and `p.y`is the x and the y of the player.

We are trying to shoot from the `me.x` and `m.y` to the `p.x` and `p.y`.

As the code stands now it justs shoots randomly every second to the right.

The canvas is 500x500.

```
me.angle = Math.atan2(p.x, p.y) / Math.PI * 180;

 me.fireBullet = function (angle) {
  var b = Bullet(me.id, angle); //bullet id, with angle pack
   b.x = me.x;
   b.y = me.y;
  }

   setInterval(function () {
     me.fireBullet(me.angle); //target angle attack
     }
       , 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Try something like: Math.atan2(p.y - me.y, p.x - m.x) * 180 / Math.PI; (notice the reversal of x and y).

Comment: This sounds like high school trigonometry. If you need a math refresher, [math.se] is the place to ask.

Comment: @MladenIlić It is still shooting the same direction... I'm not too good with my maths.

Comment: I guess you need to recalc it inside of the interval ?!

Comment: Like @JonasW pointed out: you only calculate the angle ONCE.

Comment: That's been updated now, does it every second, but still giving me a very off angle not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to find the difference between x and y took me a couple of tries but its working now.

```
var differenceX = p.x - me.x; //players x - targets x
var differenceY = p.y - me.y; //players y - targets y

me.angle = Math.atan2(differenceY, differenceX) / Math.PI * 180
```

Comment: That was mentioned in the very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tan(angle) =  y / x  | arctan()
 angle = arctan(x / y)
```

Now we only need to take the x and y of the vector going from the player to the enemy:

```
angle = Math.atan( (me.x - p.x) / m(e.y - p.y)) || 0;
```

Comment: Somehow it is still shooting the same direction, not sure why though... Shall I use atan2? Or will that not help?

Comment: @andrew doesnt matter. The problem is something else.

Comment: What is the problem? the recalculation inside the interval?

Comment: Maybe ... its hard to guess from the short extract.